# Identifying an accounts username upon login

Tags: macos

I am trying to run a launch agent upon a user logging in, but the script encapsulated by it requires knowing who is logging in. Previously I could identify the user logging in by checking the owner of /dev/console but this no longer works. The owner of /dev/console is root upon a user's login or more precisely when the launch agent runs as it changes to the user afterwards. Is there anywhere I can find out the username of a person logging in for the purposes of a launch agent?

Comment: Isn't the launch agent running in the user session anyway?

Comment: Please add the content (or at least the failing part) of the script

Comment: In the script when I set the the variable CurrentUser 
`code`
CurrentUser="$(ls -lh /dev/console | awk '{print $3}')
`code`
the variable is set to root.

Comment: Use either  `users` (which outputs the current user if only one user is logged in) or some `env | grep | awk ...` command "dissecting" the output of  LOGNAME. (i.e. `env | grep LOGNAME | awk -F = '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 1):

`CurrentUser="$(env | grep LOGNAME | awk -F = '{print $2}')"` and `$USER` used in a script launched by a launch agent in /Library/LaunchAgents both contain the username of the user logging in.

`CurrentUser="$(users)"` contains **all** users. So the first user will be revealed but logging in with a second user at the same time  (e.g. fast user switching) will break the script.